# Unable to locate the android SDK tools error

Tags: android-sdk

I have Windows 7 64bit. Installed Android Studio. SDK path is indeed `C:\Users\bill\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`. Copied pasted from explorer address bar to avoid a typo. Ran the SDK Manager and updated. Still getting the *unable to locate the android SDK tools* error. Registry is correct too.

Any idea what I am missing ?

Comment: Did you install necessary packages in SDK Manager? Also, check File -> Project Structure -> SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

its easy with the new versions of Android Studios(2.0 or higher), all you need is good internet connection.

First you will open the AVD manager, then you attempt to create a new device.
You will be diverted to new window where you will pick a hardware and navigate using a "next button" to a page where you will see all the API and you can download and install directly from there. Just click on Download and it will download and install automatically[image: Screen shot of my computer as i had my AVD manager ready to download an API for my Virtual Device].